# MongoEngine: How to append document to ListField

Tags: mongoengine

I'm using mongodb with python.

Also use MongoEngine to communicate with mongodb.

Now I made some simple board system that has comment function.

[model.py]

```
import datetime
from mongoengine import *
from config import DB_NAME


connect(DB_NAME)


class User(Document):
    no = SequenceField()
    userid = StringField(unique=True, required=True)
    userpw = StringField(required=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())


class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = StringField(required=True)
    writer = ReferenceField(User, required=True)


class Board(Document):
    no = SequenceField()
    subject = StringField(required=True)
    content = StringField(required=True)
    writer = ReferenceField(User, required=True)
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    updated_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

In this code, How can I append new list to `Board`'s `comments` field?

After searching for a hour, some document says that,

`Board.objects(no=_no).update_one(push__comments=['123', '456'])` will be works perfectly.

But it throw `mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Querying the embedded document 'Comment' failed, due to an invalid query value` error.

Maybe there is some syntax error, But I'm new at MongoEngine.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SOLVED]

```
comment = Comments(content='test', writer='hide')
board = Board.objects(no=_no).get()
board.comments.append(comment)
board.save()
```

I solved issue like this.

But, if is there any solution, please comment it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `push` operator https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html?highlight=operators#atomic-updates